# Rotating Messages with Keypress - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to rotate an array, anytime an alphanumeric key is pressed, a message displays. Below is the code I started working. I am trying to make the loop work, but it isn't working. Any feedback is appreciated.

var rotatingMessages = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(document).keypress(function(e){
var code = e.KeyCode || e.which;
var messages = (code-1) % 10;

 $("div#output").html(rotatingMessages[messages]);
  });
});
```

Comment: There is no loop. What are you trying to do. It is doing exactly what you are doing...

Comment: I am trying to rotate messages when alphanumeric key is pressed.

Comment: WHat if same key is pressed again?

Comment: It goes to the next message. Basically any alpha-numeric key will go to the next message.

Comment: I have added an answer see if that is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `shift` and `push` to enable the cycling of array values.

```
var rotatingMessages = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        var msg = rotatingMessages.shift(); //get the top value from the array
        rotatingMessages.push(msg); //push it to the end for cycle to repeat
        $("#output").html(msg);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9bU3/)**